# Access files on second NVMe

Tags: partitioning, files, nvme

I just dropped and broke one of my PCs. I am trying to access the files on the NVMe on a different machine. Both ran Ubuntu, but all I need to do is access the broken machine's NVMe that is currently in slot number 2 on my motherboard. I'm not really sure how to proceed

How would I go about accessing those?

Comment: Confusing wordage. You say those is there more then 1 HD from the old machine you are trying to access?
What is the Ubuntu version of the working machine and the one you broke? What File System is the drive from the broken machine formatted in?

Comment: Type `mount` or `df` to see if it's mounted, and where, `lsblk -f` to see what filesystem is on the drive. Also look at `sudo lshw -C disk`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that dropping the PC may have damaged the motherboard without damaging the NVMe, and all the files that were stored on the NVMe are still there ready to be accessed if the NVMe is connected to a different device.

You can buy a cheap, external caddy (NVMe storage device enclosure) for mounting the NVMe storage drive and connect it to a working computer's USB port via the caddy's USB cable. The caddy will mount automatically in Ubuntu when it is connected. Then just access it like an ordinary mounted external storage device.